# Ajax Prototype To Jquery Conversion For Innerhtml Updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototype, innerhtml

I am attempted to use jquery instead of prototype for the first time. I have a form, when you change the country on my dropdown I would like to then call another script that will bring up the appropriate list of states/provinces. In prototype I would have just used:

```
function getstates(form) {
   document.getElementById("stateresult").innerHTML="<img src='images/ajaxshippingload.gif' border='0'> Processing...";
  var checkingurl="shopgetstates.asp";
  var pars = 'country=' + form.country.value + '';
  var url = checkingurl + '?' + pars;
  var target = 'stateresult';
  var myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(target, checkingurl, {method: 'post',parameters: pars});
```

}

I am attempting to convert this into query with little success. I have come up with:

```
function getstates() {
$.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'shopgetstates.asp', data:$('#ListingForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
    $('#ListingForm').find('.stateresult').html(response);
}});

return false;
```

}

But I think this is overkill considering I only need to grab the selected value of 1 dropdown. Is there any easier way to accomplish what I am looking to do?

Comment: 1) `stateresult` seems to be an id attribute rather than a class attribute. You should use `#stateresult` instead of `.stateresult` inside the success callback. 2) In that case you don't need to use `.find()` because the id `stateresult` must be unique in the document anyway. 3) The `data` parameter of the request is different in those requests. In the prototype example it is only the country value, in the jQuery example you are serializing the whole form

Comment: Ok sloppy coding on my part, I can make those corrections. I would prefer not to use serialize and instead just get the individual values per request, is there a way to do that? and if so, how? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Like that: `data: 'country=' + form.country.value`

Comment: you, my friend, are awesome, thank you!!